# Putting my code into a nested loop

Tags: vb.net, nested-loops

Can anyone help me put this code into a nested loop please. It is a code to calculate the lowest score of candidates who have been ranked in order of preferences with 1 being the first preference and 5 being the highest.

```
Dim min = 0
    If Candidate1total > min Then
    min = Candidate1total
    LabelWINNER.Text = EnterNames.Cand1Name.Text
End If
If Candidate2total < min Then
    min = Candidate2total
    LabelWINNER.Text = EnterNames.Cand2Name.Text
End If
If Candidate3total < min Then
    min = Candidate3total
    LabelWINNER.Text = EnterNames.Cand3Name.Text
End If
If Candidate4total < min Then
    min = Candidate4total
    LabelWINNER.Text = EnterNames.Cand4Name.Text
End If
If candidate5total < min Then
    min = candidate5total
    LabelWINNER.Text = EnterNames.Cand5Name.Text
End If
```

Candidate1Total to Candidate5Total are the total scores for the candidates. This is calculated by working out the number of times a user has voted for them. The name that the candidate was given on the ENTERNAMES form is then placed in the labelWINNER if that candidate is lower then the minuim.

I think it would be something like for 0 in candidate1 total, im not 100% certain, hence asking for help.

Comment: What are `Candidate1total` and `EnterNames.Cand1Name` - depending on what these are and whether they're accessible as part of a collection will make it easier or harder to put them in a loop.

Comment: This question lacks the basic knowledge/understanding of the given programming language which is required to ask a question here. Additionally, requesting custom codes without having done anything by your own (i.e., you haven't even started the loop part) is also off-topic. Please, read the help pages and understand how SO is expected to be used.

Comment: Yes, I am being very helpful. You are not using this site as intended. The most likely outputs of this kind of off-topic posts are: not getting what you want + being downvoted (and/or flagged as low-quality and/or voted to be closed) + not contributing positively to SO at all (= just bothering others). You are new here and I have tried to help you understand how you should behave. You are free to take advantage from my advice or not (and even to seriously think that you know perfectly what you are doing and that anyone correcting your behaviour is actually doing something bad).

Comment: @RachaelMiddleditch - What do you want to happen when there is a draw?

Comment: When there is a draw I have used an array. So dim draw as array{candidate1total,candidate2total,candidate3total,candidtae4total,candidate5total}. array.sort(draw) if draw(0)=draw(1) then LabelWINNER.text=Draw

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
Dim Candidates = _
{ _
    New With { .Candidate = EnterNames.Cand1Name.Text, .Total = Candidate1total }, _
    New With { .Candidate = EnterNames.Cand2Name.Text, .Total = Candidate2total }, _
    New With { .Candidate = EnterNames.Cand3Name.Text, .Total = Candidate3total }, _
    New With { .Candidate = EnterNames.Cand4Name.Text, .Total = Candidate4total }, _
    New With { .Candidate = EnterNames.Cand5Name.Text, .Total = Candidate5total } _
}

Dim result = _
    Candidates _
        .OrderBy(Function (c) c.Total) _
        .GroupBy(Function (c) c.Total, Function (c) c.Candidate) _
        .Select(Function (c) New With { .Candidate = String.Join(", ", c), .Total = c.Key }) _
        .First()
```

So, to see the result, I used this example data:

```
Dim Candidates = _
{ _
    New With { .Candidate = "Mike", .Total = 5 }, _
    New With { .Candidate = "Tony", .Total = 2 }, _
    New With { .Candidate = "Bill", .Total = 2 }, _
    New With { .Candidate = "Carl", .Total = 3 }, _
    New With { .Candidate = "Dick", .Total = 4 } _
}
```

I got this result:

[image: result]

Of course, if it were just one candidate with the lowest total score then there would only be one name in the `Candidate` field.